# Cascading Dropdown .NET CORE

Tags: ajax, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem when Edit form with cascade dropdown but, on Create form don't have  issue, data can get from database,
I'm new on .NET Core, please explain the problem.

Here My view Create Form

[Create form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n01dr.png)

When I want to edit the data cant not retrieve from Database.
Here My View On Edit Form

[Edit Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32aOs.png)

Here my Ajax

```
 public IActionResult AjaxMethod([FromBody] AutoDetails auto)
{
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();

    switch (auto.type)
    {
        default:
            foreach (var status in this._context.EmployeeStatus)
            {
                items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = status.Name, Value = status.Id.ToString() });
            }
            break;
        case "Status":
            var employee = (from employees in this._context.Employees
                            where employees.employeeStatus.Id == auto.value
                            select employees).ToList();
            foreach (var data in employee)
            {
                items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = data.Name, Value = data.Name.ToString() });
            }
            break;
    }
    return Json(items);
}
```

Controller :

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    ViewData["team"] = _context.Teams.OrderBy(e => e.Name).ToList();
    var result = await _context.ActionItems.FindAsync(id);

    return View(result);
}
```

Here Js on Edit view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
        AjaxCall({ "type": '' }, 'Status');
    $('#ddlstatus').on('change', function () {
            var myData = {
        "type": 'Status',
    "value": $(this).find('option:selected').val()
            };
    AjaxCall(myData, 'Employee');
        });
    });

    function AjaxCall(myData, element) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ActionItems/AjaxMethod/",
            data: JSON.stringify(myData),
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                switch (element) {
                    case "Status":
                        $('#ddlstatus').append($("<option></option>").val("0").html("--Select Status--"));
                        $.each(data, function () {
                            $('#ddlstatus').append($("<option></option>").val(this.value).html(this.text));
                        });
                        $('#ddlEmp').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        break;
                    case "Employee":
                        if (data.length > 0) {
                            $('#ddlEmp').empty();
                            $('#ddlEmp').append($("<option></option>").val("0").html("--Select Name--"));
                            $.each(data, function () {
                                $('#ddlEmp').append($("<option></option>").val(this.value).html(this.text));
                            });
                            $('#ddlEmp').prop("disabled", false);;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            $('#ddlEmp').empty();
                            $('#ddlEmp').append($("<option></option>").val("0").html("--Select Name--"));
                            $('#ddlEmp').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        }
                }
            },
        });
    }</script>
```

Here My Edit View Code :

```
  <div class="row my-3">
        <div class="form-group col-5">
            <label>PIC Status</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="ddlstatus" asp-for="EmployeeStatus">
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-5">
            <label>PIC Name</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="ddlEmp" asp-for="Employee">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My model :

```
public int ActionId { get; set; }
public string ActionName { get; set; }
public string ActionTask { get; set; }
public string? ActionTaskUpdate { get; set; }
public string? Employee { get; set; }
public string? EmployeeStatus { get; set; }
public string? Team { get; set; }
public string ActionStatus { get; set; }
public string ActionCategory { get; set; }
public string CreateBy { get; set; }
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
public string? CreateDate { get; set; }
public string? UpdateDate { get; set; }
```

When I want to Edit Form, the value cant retrieve data.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @bayu chaniago , Your cascading dropdown seems generate correctly. You need share with us your edit view html code. Because Model Binding binds by `name` attribute.  Also, how is your HttpPost Edit action parameter like? I mean the parameter design, if it is a model, also share the model.

Comment: @Rena here I update edit view code, 
thanks a lot

Comment: In my code it can display the dropdown well and it also can get the value when i submit the form. So pls share more details about your requirement.

Comment: It seems you mean the second dropdown does not get the data from the database, right? Pls set breakpoint to `AjaxMethod` and check if the `auto` receive the correct value. And check if your database actually contains such record with `employeeStatus.Id` euqlas to `auto.value`.